# Generators and list comprehension

Tags: python

I wrote a generator like so:

```
def substring_gen(s):
    for i in range(len(s)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(s) +1):
            yield (s[i:j])
```

The above works fine.  But I thought I would get fancy and try to use list comprehension like this:

```
def substring_gen_lc(s):
    [yield(s[i: j]) for i in range(len(s)) for j in range(i + 1, len(s) + 1)]
```

But that is not syntactically incorrect.

Comment: Why are you telling us this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yield`s aren’t allowed in list comprehensions. You can use a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions), and return it directly because it’s already the generator you need:

```
def substring_gen_lc(s):
    return (s[i:j] for i in range(len(s)) for j in range(i + 1, len(s) + 1))
```

But in general, there’s no need to get fancy. Using list comprehensions for side effects is a particularly bad kind of fancy, even.

Answer (score 0):

No need for the yield, it's both redundant and syntactically incorrect.  It's purpose is to *yield* one item at a time in place of `return`.

Just use:

```
return [s[i: j] for i in range(len(s)) for j in range(i + 1, len(s) + 1)]
```